# JDBC SQL Server query timeout

Tags: java, sql-server, maven, timeout

I'm working on a Java application built with Maven. The application works with data from a local SQL Server database. Is is very common for the SQL Server at my workplace to be unavailable (several power outages), so I'd like to set a shorter timeout for the system to throw an exception.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection
```

The idea is not to have the application hanging for ~30 seconds before letting us know the server is unavailable.

I've tried including the socketTimeout and queryTimeout properties in the Datasource's URL as indicated in [these](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/wiki/SocketTimout) [two](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/wiki/QueryTimeout) links, but to no avail. Is there any way to set a global timeout for this?

Answer (score 0):

Via jdbcTemplate:

```
JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
template.setQueryTimeout(30);
```

Comment: I did change the jdbcTemplate's queryTimeout via the ApplicationContext.xml file.

`<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">`
     `<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>`
     `<property name="queryTimeout" value="1"></property>`
 `</bean>`

However, it doesn't appear to make a difference.